# Detecting Pig-Latin In Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've tried to write a function to do this but can't get GHCI to understand my code. I'm coming from an OOP background so functional programming is completely new territory for me.

```
checkPigLatin :: String -> String
checkPigLatin sentence (x:xs)
    | check == "true" = "This is Pig Latin"
    | otherwise = "Not Pig Latin"
    where check = if (x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU", '-' `elem` xs, snd(break('a'==) xs) == 'a', snd(break('a'==) xs) == 'y') then "true"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do inside the `if`? You seem to be constructing a triple there: that won't work. The expression after `if` needs to evaluate to a `Bool`. You are also missing the `else` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. The type of your function is `String -> String`, so it should only have one argument, while your definition has two arguments, `sentence` and `(x:xs)`.
2. Don't use strings like `"true"` and `"false"`. Use booleans. That's what they're for.
3. The condition of an `if` must be a boolean. If you want several conditions to hold, use `(&&)` or `and` to combine them.
4. An `if`-expression must have both a `then` and an `else`. You can think of `if x then y else z` like the ternary `x ? y : z` operator in  some other languages.
5. `'a'` and `'y'` have type `Char`, so you can't compare them against strings with `==`. Compare with `"a"` and `"y"` instead.

However, there is no point in writing `if something then True else False`. Instead, just use the boolean expression directly.

```
checkPigLatin :: String -> String
checkPigLatin (x:xs)
    | check     = "This is Pig Latin"
    | otherwise = "Not Pig Latin"
    where check = and [ x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU"
                      , '-' `elem` xs
                      , snd (break ('a'==) xs) == "a"
                      , snd (break ('a'==) xs) == "y"
                      ]
```

Comment: And what about `checkPigLatin ""` ?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ: Yes, you probably want to add a case for the empty string as well. Also, I haven't checked if this actually does the right thing, I only focused on the syntax and type errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input guys. And thanks, Hammar for pointing out all the flaws of the function, it really helps in the learning process.
However, I'm afraid it still doesn't accomplish what I want it to. For example checkPigLatin "eck-chay ig-pay atin-lay" should have worked. 
The three essential characteristics for Pig Latin are that it begins with a vowel, it has "-" and ends with "ay". I thought the function was checking for all that. Idk what's wrong.

Comment: @rexbelia: You can check for the latter by using ```"ay" `isSuffixOf` xs``` (you may have to import `Data.List`). The vowel and `'-'` checks look like they're OK.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Just a general question, where exactly is "if" used if this is not an appropriate to use it?

Comment: @rexbelia: Many places. It's just that `if x then True else False` is the same as just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but they're all minor.

- When you say `checkPigLatin sentence (x:xs)`, you are saying that your function takes two arguments: `sentence`, and `(x:xs)`. What you mean to say is just `(x:xs)`.
- There's no need to return `"true"`, which is a `String`, when you can return `True :: Bool`. `Bool` is already the type that the expression inside the `if` returns. This means you don't need the `if` statement at all.
- In the predicate in the parentheses, you use `,` as the logical AND, but in Haskell it's  `&&`
- The result of `break` is a string, so write `"a"` for its second argument, not `'a'`
- Lastly - and this is about pig latin, not Haskell - I'm not sure that failing `(snd(break('a'==) xs) == "a")` is going to guarantee something is not pig latin

Hope this helps, and welcome!

*Edit:*
Here's the updated code, if you'd like it:

```
checkPigLatin :: String -> String
checkPigLatin (x:xs)
    | check = "This is Pig Latin"
    | otherwise = "Not Pig Latin"
    where check = (x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU") &&
                  ('-' `elem` xs) && 
                  (snd(break('a'==) xs) == "a") && 
                  (snd(break('a'==) xs) == "y")
```

Comment: Thanks. The second snd(break()) should be (snd(break('y'==) xs) == "y") right? I know it's not going to guarantee that something is not Pig Latin, but should it actually be Pig Latin it wouldn't fail right? Do you have any alternatives in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what's going on in that string-checks, but maybe this is what you need.

```
checkPigLatin :: String -> String
checkPigLatin [] = "Empty string"
checkPigLatin (x:xs)
    | check = "This is Pig Latin"
    | otherwise = "Not Pig Latin"
    where check = and [ x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU"
                      , '-' `elem` xs
                      , snd ( break ('a' == ) xs ) == "a"
                      , snd (break ('a' == ) xs) == "y"
                      ]
```

And

```
pisya> checkPigLatin "checkPigLatin"
"Not Pig Latin"
it :: String
```